# SDL changing cursor to Windows default

Tags: c++, sdl, mouse-cursor

I'm making a simple windowed game and I want a standard system cursor instead of SDL's black one. Is this possible without manual creation of cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know. Because SDL works on all major platforms, even those without default cursors, SDL creators decided to always use a custom cursor. Drawing the default system cursor shouldn't be that hard though - just load the .cur file and paint it as a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for you to to display 4 types of default SDL cursors with the help of SDL_CreateCursor. The SDL documentation provides this information:

http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_CreateCursor

Comment: Now I don't mind changing it - the default default cursor (black one) is good enough.

Comment: There are 2 options for a cursor color - black and white. The white color looks quite like the windows default cursor.